# URL shows up the directory after URL MASKING with .htaccess :-> PHP

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

i just updated my .htaccess to mask a localhost url , but after masking , when i ran the url . it is showing me the directory structure , which it should not . Am new to the concept of url masking .

Can anyone help me on this .

Below is my directory structure

```
http://localhost/CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/index.php
```

and below is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?CentralizedUI/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/index.php/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?/CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^
RewriteRule ^.+$ CentralizedUI/
```

when i run the url it shows

[image: Structure]

**what i want is to remove the directory name and extension of file in URL .**

**I updated the code :**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(?:CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/)?(.*)$ /CentralizedUI/$1 [NC,L]
```

but am not able to remove extension .php

**New Edit Based On Answer From Ravinder **

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/([^.]*)\.php/?$ /CentralizedUI/$1? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^CentralizedUI/(.*)/?$ CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/index.php [L]
```

Comment: could you please confirm by Rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?/CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/index.php` what you are trying to achieve here? Do you want to redirect any url other than `CentralizedUI` TO `CentralizedUI` in broswer? Please confirm once.

Comment: no , i just want to remove extension and folder path from this url "http://localhost/CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/index.php" , since am new to this masking conceot . i don know what to do @RavinderSingh13

Comment: not an issue, we all are here to learn. Please do tell me one more thing, you are hitting url `http://localhost/CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/index.php` in your browser? Which you want to change to `http://localhost/CentralizedUI` in browser? Please confirm me like this, then only we could get more clear picture of question.

Comment: yeah , what you said is right , and i have many php file inside CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default this folder , for all those files it should not show the path , not extension @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Ok so when you hit as an example `http://localhost/CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/test.php` in browser so should it change to `http://localhost/CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/test`? in browser? Please confirm once.

Comment: no when i hit ***http://localhost/CentralizedUI/CentralizedDashboardNew/html/demos/default/test.php*** it should be  ***http://localhost/test*** @RavinderSingh13